# Autocad Vba ----- Entity non-uniform resize

Tags: vba, resize, scale, autocad, uniform

I am trying to write a VBA program for Autocad, and one of its function has to allow the user to select an entity in Autocad and scale it none uniformly. Currently i see offset and scaleentity method, but as far as i can tell, they are both uniform resizing. 
My current code use selectionSets, AcadEntity and selectOnScreen to accomplish the target selection. So is there any VBA code to scale the selected entity none uniformly?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to scale entities non-uniformly in the AutoCAD designer itself, I wonder if it could by any API at all. It ís however possible for blocks.

So you might want to try to (temporarily) convert the entity to a block, insert the block with different X, Y (and Z) scales, explode it and delete the block reference again.